# Sass error : This selector doesn't have any properties

Tags: css, sass

I got an error when i compile the scss file to css file by using this command

> C:\Ruby23>sass --watch C:\Users\Saif\Desktop\Torcan Website:C:\Users\Saif\Desktop\Torcan Website\css

[image]

And this is this scss code

```css
$c :blue;
body
{
 color: $c;
}
```

Could you help

Comment: Which sass compiler are you using? Because you are using SCSS syntax. Maybe the compiler is giving error because of it. Get rid of the brackets and colons and then try.

Comment: I tired it,  i got the same error